# Faulty TensorFlow C install on MacOS?: dyld errors "Library not loaded: @rpath/libtensorflow.1.dylib" and "Symbol not found: __cg_DGifCloseFile"

Tags: c, tensorflow, dyld

## Question

How should I install the TensorFlow C library on MacOS or otherwise address the errors:

```sh
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtensorflow.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Me/./hello_tf
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

and

```sh
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_DGifCloseFile
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libGIF.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Abort trap: 6
```

## Context

I followed the [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) for MacOS using the “macOS CPU only” library verbatim until the `sudo ldconfig` bit.  This being Mac, I substituted `update_dyld_shared_cache` for `ldconfig` and restarted, then built the example program provided.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>
int main() {
  printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
  return 0;
}
```

I got:

```sh
~$ gcc hello_tf.c -ltensorflow -o hello_tf
~$ ./hello_tf
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtensorflow.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Me/./hello_tf
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Following the instructions’ advice, I rebuild with `gcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib hello_tf.c -ltensorflow -o hello_tf` and got the same result.

The installation instructions say to set `LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` for installs in non-system directories.  I decided to give it a shot:

```sh
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

Compiling with both methods (that is, without and with `-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib`) now give me:

```sh
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_DGifCloseFile
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libGIF.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Abort trap: 6
```

(Well, at least it’s a different error.)

My `/usr/local/lib` contains the TensorFlow files:

```
libtensorflow.1.14.0.dylib
libtensorflow.1.dylib
libtensorflow.dylib
libtensorflow_framework.1.14.0.dylib
libtensorflow_framework.1.dylib
libtensorflow_framework.dylib
```

`libtensorflow.dylib` and `libtensorflow.1.dylib` are links that point to `libtensorflow.1.14.0.dylib`, and `libtensorflow_framework.dylib` and `libtensorflow_framework.1.dylib` likewise point to `libtensorflow.1.14.0.dylib`, as in the provided `.tar.gz` archive.

## Desired Outcome

The primary desired effect is that the following occurs:

```sh
~$ gcc hello_tf.c -ltensorflow -o hello_tf
~$ ./hello_tf
Hello from TensorFlow C library version 1.14.0
```

(That’s the version I’m using.)

A secondary desired effect is understanding of why the mentioned errors occurred.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by installing with Homebrew, adding `/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and compiling with the `-ltensorflow` flag as the last of the GCC arguments.  It seems dyld is rather picky; if possible, I’d still like to have a better explanation than that.

```sh
~$ brew install libtensorflow
 # Homebrew output omitted
~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib"
~$ gcc hello_tf.c -o hello_tf -ltensorflow
~$ ./hello_tf
TensorFlow C lib version 1.14.0
```

This also didn’t work with the modifications to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` mentioned in the question.

It might be wise to add `/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.bash_profile` or some build script.