# Resolve "ld: library not found for -ltensorflow_framework.2.3.0"

Tags: c++, xcode, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a hello world macOS project that runs Tensorflow models. Documentation for Tensorflow (not to be confused by Tensorflow Lite) lack instructions on how to add the libtensorflow_framework to an XCode project that targets macOS.

What I did so far is:

1. create a conda environment (pip, python3.8.3)
2. pip install tensorflow==2.3.0rc0
3. locate the path to the tensorflow package, and drag and drop the `libtensorflow_framework.2.3.0.dylib` file into a group called `lib` that is located directly under the project root.

The I tried to run the app, but I got the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -ltensorflow_framework.2.3.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

which doesn't even make sense, because the file name is `libtensorflow_framework.2.3.0.dylib` and not `ltensorflow_framework.2.3.0`

Comment: The linker usually prefixes with lib and suffixes with either dylib or lib, so if it only says `library not found for -ltensorflow_framework.2.3.0`, the message makes sense if it cannot find `libtensorflow_framework.2.3.0.dylib`. Can you check in xcode if the linker is searching in the path where you put `libtensorflow`? https://blogs.wcode.org/2014/11/howto-setup-xcode-6-1-to-work-with-opencv-libraries/ should help.

Comment: @MikaelH thanks, I looked into that link, added the library and header search paths and now the app builds successfully. However, I'm presented with another error now `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-aydwnfuhwpganbawdedqbnxoakik/Build/Products/Debug/myproject.app/Contents/MacOS/myproject
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: Hm, I don't know (I don't use Mac nor do I use xcode or tensorflow). I would guess that the error is rather searchable. Do you find some useful info here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-found.

Comment: @MikaelH I understand. I appreciate you looking into this. I actually finally solved the loading issue by downloading through Homebrew using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57937424/4112200 and then making sure the dylib and header files are reachable. Now, I get this error trying to print the TensorFlow version `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TF_Version", referenced from:`. Do you happen to know if this means I should build TensorFlow from source?

Comment: It seems the library is not correctly linked to the project that is using it. You should not necessarily need to build it, but it's a bit hard to know with this info. Maybe check here and see if it solves it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure what was the cause of that problem. However, I was able to finally link Tensorflow 2.2.0 to my Xcode project. (thanks to the hints that @Mikael H provided)

Here's what I did:

1. I installed TensorFlow using `brew` instead of `python/pip`.

```
brew install libtensorflow
```

2. I checked that `/usr/local/include` has the `./tensorflow/` headers and I added this path to the Xcode `Header Search Path`.
3. I checked that `/usr/local/lib` has the `dylib` files and added the path to `Library Search Path`.
4. I added the following arguments `-ltensorflow -ltensorflow_framework.2.2.0` to the `Other Linker Arguments`.

You can find the `Header Search Path`, `Library Search Path`, and `Other Linker Arguments` by going to your target's settings -> Build Settings -> All & Combined.